# Add "appointed mm/dd/yyyy" information for pro tempore mods to the moderators tab of the users page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderators, beta-sites

If you go to a graduated site - say, Server Fault - and check out [the moderators tab of the users page](https://serverfault.com/users?tab=moderators), you see this (truncated for space):

[image: half the mods on Server Fault]

If, on the other hand, you go to a beta site - e.g. Aviation - and check out [the same page](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), you see this (again, truncated):

[image: half the mods on Aviation]

Would it be possible to get analogous "appointed mm/dd/yyyy" information for pro tempore moderators on beta sites? Presumably, the text would link to the meta post in which the moderators were named as such (for Aviation, that would be [this post](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/203/93)).

Relatedly, this data is also absent from the ["all network moderators"](https://stackexchange.com/about/moderators?by=users) page, and it would be nice if it were there too.

(I have no real reason for making this request other than that it would be an interesting piece of trivia to have on beta sites, particularly those that have been in beta for a long time and have had some shuffling of moderators.)

Comment: Related: http://xkcd.com/1179/

Comment: For a logged in moderator, the text should read: "You have spent **782** days of your life as a moderator. Don't you have anything better to do?"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The moderators tab of the users page now shows appointment dates for pro-tem mods in addition to election dates for elected mods. Enjoy!

Comment: Please [fix the date format](http://xkcd.com/1179/) for the 95% of the population who isn't used to reading dates in a mixed order and for consistency with the rest of Stack Exchange which uses yyyy-mm-dd.